# Conditionally merge primary and secondary dictionary in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to merge two dictionaries that contain settings for a number of apps. In the primary dictionary, which is attached to individual hosts, it contains the stuff that is specific to that server (e.g. versions that relate to the git repo of the app):

#### proj/host_vars/host_name.yml

```
installed_apps:
  pineapple:
    version: master
  pear:
    version: "1.1"
```

Then the secondary one contains all the settings specific to the app:

#### proj/group_vars/apps.yml

```
all_apps:
  pineapple:
    setting1: blah
    setting2: di
    setting3: blah
  apple:
    setting1: hi
  pear:
    setting3: there
```

From these I want to construct a dictionary that combines the values of both **but only if the app exists in "installed_apps"** so that ansible has all the details for all the apps it needs to install on a certain server:

```
new_dict:
  pineapple:
    version: master
    setting1: blah
    setting2: di
    setting3: blah
  pear:
    version: "1.1"
    setting3: there
```

In Python it would go something like this:

```
installed_apps = {
    "pineapple": {"version": "master"},
    "pear": {"version": "1.1"}
}

all_apps = {
    'pineapple': {'setting1': 'blah', 'setting2': 'di', 'setting3': 'blah'},
    'apple': {'setting1': 'hi'},
    'pear': {'setting3': 'there'}
}

new_dict = dict()
for k, v in all_apps.items():
    if k in installed_apps:
        new_dict[k] = v
        new_dict[k].update(installed_apps[k])
```

But I can't for the life of me work out how to do this in Ansible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using Ansible's [combine](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) filter.

The following examples assume the following:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    installed_apps:
      pineapple:
        version: master
      pear:
        version: "1.1"
    all_apps:
        pineapple:
          setting1: blah
          setting2: di
          setting3: blah
        apple:
          setting1: hi
        pear:
          setting3: there
```

First, we create a new dictionary (`installed_app_settings`) that consists of those items in `all_apps` that have a matching key in `installed_apps`:

```
- set_fact:
    installed_app_settings: >
      {{ (installed_app_settings|default([])) + [{item: all_apps[item]}] }}
  with_items: "{{ installed_apps }}"

- debug:
    var: installed_app_settings
```

Now we use that to update the `installed_apps` variable with the values extracted in the previous `set_fact` task:

```
- set_fact:
    installed_apps: >
      {{ installed_apps|combine(item, recursive=True) }}
  with_items: "{{ installed_app_settings }}"

- debug:
    var: installed_apps
```

Which results in:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "installed_apps": {
        "pear": {
            "setting3": "there", 
            "version": "1.1"
        }, 
        "pineapple": {
            "setting1": "blah", 
            "setting2": "di", 
            "setting3": "blah", 
            "version": "master"
        }
    }
}
```

...which I think is what you were after.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Only thing I added was a loop_control `label: "{{ item.keys() }}"` on the second set_fact so that it doesn't spam stdout with all the settings.